# Is there a better way to walk a directory tree?

Tags: haskell, recursion, directory

I just started to learn Haskell, and i wrote a function that walks the directory tree recursively and pass the content of each directory to a callback function:

- The content of the directory is a tuple, containing a list of all the sub-directories, and a list of file names.
- If there is an error, the error is passed to the callback function instead of the directory content (it use `Either`).

So here is the type of the callback function:

```haskell
callback :: FileName -> Either IOError ([FileName], [FileName]) -> IO ()
```

And here is the type of my `walk` function:

```haskell
walk :: FilePath -> (FilePath -> Either IOError ([FilePath], [FilePath]) -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

And here is my complete code:

```haskell
module Test where
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import Control.Monad (filterM, forM_, return)
import System.IO.Error (tryIOError, IOError)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesFileExist, doesDirectoryExist)



myVisitor :: FilePath -> Either IOError ([FilePath], [FilePath]) -> IO ()
myVisitor path result = do
    case result of
        Left error -> do
            putStrLn $ "I've tryed to look in " ++ path ++ "."
            putStrLn $ "\tThere was an error: "
            putStrLn $ "\t\t" ++ (show error)

        Right (dirs, files) -> do
            putStrLn $ "I've looked in " ++ path ++ "."
            putStrLn $ "\tThere was " ++ (show $ length dirs) ++ " directorie(s) and " ++ (show $ length files) ++ " file(s):"
            forM_ (dirs ++ files) (\x -> putStrLn $ "\t\t- " ++ x)
    putStrLn ""


walk :: FilePath -> (FilePath -> Either IOError ([FilePath], [FilePath]) -> IO ()) -> IO ()
walk path visitor = do 
    result <- tryIOError listdir

    case result of
        Left error -> do
            visitor path result

        Right (dirs, files) -> do
            visitor path result
            forM_
                (map (\x -> path </> x) dirs) 
                (\x -> walk x visitor)

    where
        listdir = do
            entries <-  (getDirectoryContents path) >>= filterHidden
            subdirs <- filterM isDir entries
            files <- filterM isFile entries
            return (subdirs, files)
            where 
                isFile entry = doesFileExist (path </> entry)
                isDir entry = doesDirectoryExist (path </> entry)
                filterHidden paths = do 
                    return $ filter (\path -> head path /= '.') paths


main :: IO ()
main = do
    walk "/tmp" myVisitor
    walk "foo bar" myVisitor
    putStrLn "Done :-/"
```

As you can see, there is a lot of code and i `import` a lot of things... 
I'm sure there is a better way to do that, and i'm interested in any 
`{idea,hint,tip}` to improve this piece of code.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the concept of iteratees/pipes that can be used to solve this problem. It allows you to separate producing the tree and consuming it somewhere else without direct callback functions: You create a producer that enumerates the directory tree, perhaps some filters that modify the data and a separate consumer that works on the data. And then compose and run the whole pipeline. See also [Streaming recursive descent of a directory in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14259229/1333025).

There are also specialized Haskell packages for that such as [directory-tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-tree), which you can use or study.

---

**Edit:** As an example I reworked your code using [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit). This library (and others based on the same principle) has several advantages, namely:

- It separates the producer of the data with its consumer.
- In a source you just call `yield` when you want to send a piece of data to the pipe.
- In a sink you call `await` whenever you want to receive a piece of data (here we used more specialized `awaitForever`).
- You can have *conduits* that sit in the middle and consume and produce values at the same time. They can do whatever processing on the stream, mixing calls to `yield` and `await` as they wish.
- This allows you to create complex computation where the behavior of your components depends on data sent/deceived earlier. We use this in our source (traversing a directory tree), and I also added it to the sink (visitor) - it keeps track of how many directories it has been passed so far.
- Both source and sink (and intermediate conduits, if any) can have finalizers.

Some suggestions:

1. Create your own data types instead of using combinations of `Either` and `(,)`. It makes your code shorter and easier to understand.
2. Sometimes it's worth declaring new functions instead of using complex `case ... of` expressions. It can make code easier to read.
3. [hlint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) can suggest how to (syntactically) improve a piece of code.

---

```
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import Control.Monad (filterM, forM_, return)
import System.IO.Error (tryIOError, IOError)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesFileExist, doesDirectoryExist)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.Conduit

data DirContent = DirList [FilePath] [FilePath]
                | DirError IOError
data DirData = DirData FilePath DirContent

-- Produces directory data
walk :: FilePath -> Source IO DirData
walk path = do 
    result <- lift $ tryIOError listdir
    case result of
        Right dl@(DirList subdirs files)
            -> do
                yield (DirData path dl)
                forM_ subdirs (walk . (path </>))
        Left error
            -> yield (DirData path (DirError error))

  where
    listdir = do
        entries <- getDirectoryContents path >>= filterHidden
        subdirs <- filterM isDir entries
        files <- filterM isFile entries
        return $ DirList subdirs files
        where 
            isFile entry = doesFileExist (path </> entry)
            isDir entry = doesDirectoryExist (path </> entry)
            filterHidden paths = return $ filter (\path -> head path /= '.') paths

-- Consume directories
myVisitor :: Sink DirData IO ()
myVisitor = addCleanup (\_ -> putStrLn "Finished.") $ loop 1
  where
    loop n = do
        lift $ putStrLn $ ">> " ++ show n ++ ". directory visited:"
        r <- await
        case r of
            Nothing     -> return ()
            Just r      -> lift (process r) >> loop (n + 1)
    process (DirData path (DirError error)) = do
        putStrLn $ "I've tried to look in " ++ path ++ "."
        putStrLn $ "\tThere was an error: "
        putStrLn $ "\t\t" ++ show error

    process (DirData path (DirList dirs files)) = do
        putStrLn $ "I've looked in " ++ path ++ "."
        putStrLn $ "\tThere was " ++ show (length dirs) ++ " directorie(s) and " ++ show (length files) ++ " file(s):"
        forM_ (dirs ++ files) (putStrLn . ("\t\t- " ++))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    walk "/tmp" $$ myVisitor
```

Comment: I don't want to add too many dependencies to my software, so i won't use
`directory-tree` ; However, `conduit` seems great and can probably be used in
sereral parts of my software, so i think i will use it. Anyway, your code is
more cleaner than mine, especially the 2ⁿᵈ function.  
Thanks for your response
:-)